# Using one lookup table for multiple columns in another table with SQLite

Tags: sql, r, sqlite

Using one lookup table for multiple columns in another table with SQLite

I need to use a lookup table Switch (with NAs) multiple times (multiple references) in table SwitchLinkage (also with NAs) (only selected data provided for both tables).

Table: Switch

| SwitchID | Name | DefaultInputOutputSwitchAsgnCode | AccessibleForInput | AccessibleForOutput | Disp_ImageSetInstanceID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1380 | T: Anches Pedal (Stop Screen) | 2020 |  |  | 1380 |
| 1381 | T: Anches Cornet (Stop Screen) | 2120 |  |  | 1381 |
| 1382 | T: Anches Bombarde (Stop Screen | 2119 |  |  | 1382 |
| 1383 | T: Anches Recit (Stop Screen) | 2213 |  |  | 1383 |
| 1392 | T: Tremolo (Stop Screen) | 2214 |  |  | 1392 |
| 1393 | T: TremoloGO. |  |  |  | 1393 |
| 1394 | T: TremoloBom |  |  |  | 1394 |
| 1395 | T: TremoloRec |  |  |  | 1395 |
| 1493 | T: TremoloGO. |  |  |  | 1493 |
| 1494 | T: TremoloBom |  |  |  | 1494 |
| 1495 | T: TremoloRec |  |  |  | 1495 |
| 2080 | T: Anches Pedal (Extend) |  | Y | Y | 2080 |
| 2081 | T: Anches Cornet (Extend) |  | Y | Y | 2081 |
| 2082 | T: Anches Bombarde (Extend) |  | Y | Y | 2082 |
| 2083 | T: Anches Recit (Extend) |  | Y | Y | 2083 |
| 12080 | T: Anches Pedal (Split Screen) |  | Y | Y | 12080 |
| 12081 | T: Anches Cornet (Split Screen) |  |  |  | 12081 |
| 12082 | T: Anches Bombarde (Split Scree |  |  |  | 12082 |
| 12083 | T: Anches Recit (Split Screen) |  |  |  | 12083 |

Table: SwitchLinkage

| SourceSwitchID | DestSwitchID | ConditionSwitchID | SourceSwitchLinkIfEngaged | ConditionSwitchLinkIfEngaged | ReevaluateIfCondSwitchChangesState | EngageLinkActionCode | DisengageLinkActionCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1380 | 12080 |  | Y | N | Y | 1 | 2 |
| 1381 | 12081 |  | Y | N | Y | 1 | 2 |
| 1382 | 12082 |  | Y | N | Y | 1 | 2 |
| 1383 | 12083 |  | Y | N | Y | 1 | 2 |
| 1393 | 1493 | 1392 | Y | Y | Y | 1 | 2 |
| 1394 | 1494 | 1392 | Y | Y | Y | 1 | 2 |
| 1395 | 1495 | 1392 | Y | Y | Y | 1 | 2 |
| 2080 | 11080 |  | Y | N | Y | 1 | 2 |
| 2081 | 11081 |  | Y | N | Y | 1 | 2 |
| 2082 | 11082 |  | Y | N | Y | 1 | 2 |
| 2083 | 11083 |  | Y | N | Y | 1 | 2 |
| 12080 | 1380 |  | Y | N | Y | 1 | 2 |
| 12081 | 1381 |  | Y | N | Y | 1 | 2 |
| 12082 | 1382 |  | Y | N | Y | 1 | 2 |
| 12083 | 1383 |  | Y | N | Y | 1 | 2 |

In table SwitchLinkage:
(SourceSwitchID) REFERENCES Switch (SwitchID)
(DestSwitchID) REFERENCES Switch (SwitchID)
(ConditionSwitchID) REFERENCES Switch (SwitchID)

I provided an example of what I want to achieve in table Final. NAs should be allowed as per the input tables.

Table: Final

| SourceSwitchID | Name_SourceSwitch | AsgnCode_SourceSwitch | DestSwitchID | Name_DestSwitch | AsgnCode_DestSwitch | ConditionSwitchID | Name_ConditionSwitch | AsgnCode_ConditionSwitch | SourceSwitchLinkIfEngaged | EngageLinkActionCode | DisengageLinkActionCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1380 | T: Anches Pedal (Stop Screen) | 2020 | 12080 | T: Anches Pedal (Split Screen) |  |  |  |  | Y | 1 | 2 |
| 1381 | T: Anches Cornet (Stop Screen) | 2120 | 12081 | T: Anches Cornet (Split Screen) |  |  |  |  | Y | 1 | 2 |
| 1382 | T: Anches Bombarde (Stop Screen | 2119 | 12082 | T: Anches Bombarde (Split Scree |  |  |  |  | Y | 1 | 2 |
| 1383 | T: Anches Recit (Stop Screen) | 2213 | 12083 | T: Anches Recit (Split Screen) |  |  |  |  | Y | 1 | 2 |
| 1393 | T: TremoloGO. |  | 1493 | T: TremoloGO. |  | 1392 | T: Tremolo (Stop Screen) | 2214 | Y | 1 | 2 |
| 1394 | T: TremoloBom |  | 1494 | T: TremoloBom |  | 1392 | T: Tremolo (Stop Screen) | 2214 | Y | 1 | 2 |
| 1395 | T: TremoloRec |  | 1495 | T: TremoloRec |  | 1392 | T: Tremolo (Stop Screen) | 2214 | Y | 1 | 2 |
| 2080 | T: Anches Pedal (Extend) |  | 11080 |  |  |  |  |  | Y | 1 | 2 |
| 2081 | T: Anches Cornet (Extend) |  | 11081 |  |  |  |  |  | Y | 1 | 2 |
| 2082 | T: Anches Bombarde (Extend) |  | 11082 |  |  |  |  |  | Y | 1 | 2 |
| 2083 | T: Anches Recit (Extend) |  | 11083 |  |  |  |  |  | Y | 1 | 2 |
| 12080 | T: Anches Pedal (Split Screen) |  | 1380 | T: Anches Pedal (Stop Screen) | 2020 |  |  |  | Y | 1 | 2 |
| 12081 | T: Anches Cornet (Split Screen) |  | 1381 | T: Anches Cornet (Stop Screen) | 2120 |  |  |  | Y | 1 | 2 |
| 12082 | T: Anches Bombarde (Split Scree |  | 1382 | T: Anches Bombarde (Stop Screen | 2119 |  |  |  | Y | 1 | 2 |
| 12083 | T: Anches Recit (Split Screen) |  | 1383 | T: Anches Recit (Stop Screen) | 2213 |  |  |  | Y | 1 | 2 |

I have no idea how to do this and would appreciate any form of help.

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example with just part of the data and a few of the columns.
It's just an `outer join / LEFT JOIN` between each `Switch` and the `Linkage` table. Any missing links will just produce `NULL` in the result for the corresponding columns.

Use derived column names, as needed, to adjust the columns in the result.

It's not clear if there's any other logic you're asking about.

The test case:

[Working Test Case for sqlite](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=1a7d185f2770896df3d1838f393bbd53)

The SQL:

```
SELECT s1.SwitchID, s1.Name, s1.DefaultInputOutputSwitchAsgnCode AS SwitchAsgnCode
     , s2.SwitchID, s2.Name, s2.DefaultInputOutputSwitchAsgnCode AS SwitchAsgnCode
     , s3.SwitchID, s3.Name, s3.DefaultInputOutputSwitchAsgnCode AS SwitchAsgnCode
  FROM SwitchLinkage           AS sw
  LEFT JOIN Switch             AS s1
    ON sw.SourceSwitchID      = s1.SwitchID
  LEFT JOIN Switch             AS s2
    ON sw.DestSwitchID        = s2.SwitchID
  LEFT JOIN Switch             AS s3
    ON sw.ConditionSwitchID   = s3.SwitchID
 ORDER BY s1.SwitchID
;
```

The result:

```
+----------+---------------------------------+----------------+----------+---------------------------------+----------------+----------+--------------------------+----------------+
| SwitchID | Name                            | SwitchAsgnCode | SwitchID | Name                            | SwitchAsgnCode | SwitchID | Name                     | SwitchAsgnCode |
+----------+---------------------------------+----------------+----------+---------------------------------+----------------+----------+--------------------------+----------------+
|     1380 | T: Anches Pedal (Stop Screen)   |           2020 |    12080 | T: Anches Pedal (Split Screen)  |           NULL |     NULL | NULL                     |           NULL |
|     1381 | T: Anches Cornet (Stop Screen)  |           2120 |    12081 | T: Anches Cornet (Split Screen) |           NULL |     NULL | NULL                     |           NULL |
|     1382 | T: Anches Bombarde (Stop Screen |           2119 |    12082 | T: Anches Bombarde (Split Scree |           NULL |     NULL | NULL                     |           NULL |
|     1393 | T: TremoloGO.                   |           NULL |     1493 | T: TremoloGO.                   |           NULL |     1392 | T: Tremolo (Stop Screen) |           2214 |
|     1394 | T: TremoloBom                   |           NULL |     1494 | T: TremoloBom                   |           NULL |     1392 | T: Tremolo (Stop Screen) |           2214 |
|     1395 | T: TremoloRec                   |           NULL |     1495 | T: TremoloRec                   |           NULL |     1392 | T: Tremolo (Stop Screen) |           2214 |
+----------+---------------------------------+----------------+----------+---------------------------------+----------------+----------+--------------------------+----------------+
```